# Unable todisplay Image in Datatables (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, datatables

I have searched the entire Internet. Everything was going well, I was uploading and retreiving imagens with NodeJs to MongoDB using the following schema:

```
image: {
    data: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/public/uploads/', req.file.filename)),
    contentType: req.file.mimetype
},
```

It was quite simple to display images with pug :

```
img(src='data:'+data.image.contentType+';base64,'+data.image.data.toString('base64') rel='nofollow' alt='...')
```

Problems started when I tried to display the images in dataTables like this:

```
$(nTd).html("<img src='data:image/"+oData.image.contentType+";base64,"+oData.image.data.toString('base64')+"' class='rounded-circle' height='53'>");
```

It does not work, no matter what I try, the result is allways:

```
<img src="data:image/image/jpeg;base64,[object Object]" class="rounded-circle" height="53">`
```

Please help.

Part of my server side script

```
Candidato.find(searchStr, 'image nome status createdAt vaga',{ sort: {[sortColumn]: sortOrder}, 'skip': Number( req.body.start), 'limit': Number(req.body.length) }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) {
                console.log(chalk.red('erro ao obter resultados'+err));
                return;
        }
        var data = JSON.stringify({
                "draw": req.body.draw,
                "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
                "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
                "data": results
            });
            res.send(data);
        });
```

Comment: Does pug run on the server (node.js)? If so, that's probably why it works and your dataTables/jQuery doesn't, since it would have to run client side, in the browser. You won't be able to send the resulting `Buffer` from `readFileSync` to a client browser: it's a node.js thing. You'd already need to have done your `.toString('base64')` before sending image object to the browser.

Comment: Thanks! That´s the problem. Any hints so I can do thany in my server side script? [In my edit]

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used the Mongoose lean() method in order to return documents in plain javascript! –

```js
Usuario.find(searchStr, 'image.thumbnail nome tipo status createdAt',{ sort: {[sortColumn]: sortOrder}, 'skip': Number( req.body.start), 'limit': Number(req.body.length) }, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(chalk.red('erro ao obter resultados'+err));
        return;
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "draw": req.body.draw,
        "recordsFiltered": recordsFiltered,
        "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
        "data": results
    });
    res.send(data);
}).lean();;
```